# Assign curl http reponse code to variable

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I've got the following call in a bash script I'm creating

```
response= curl -X POST $URL -u "$USER:$PASSWORD" --data-urlencode "key=$key" --data "label=pub_key" -o /dev/null --silent --write-out "%{http_code}"
```

I can see 200 being written to the console however $response always ends up null.

I've also tried the following but it was not better.

```
response= $(curl -X POST $URL -u "$USER:$PASSWORD" --data-urlencode "key=$key" --data "label=pub_key" -o /dev/null --silent --write-out "%{http_code}")
```

Any help for a bash noob would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Space -- the final frontier:

```
response=$(curl -X ...)
```

Note: no spaces around the `=`. The shell is white-space sensitive in a few places and variable assignments are one of them.

With the space, as in `var= command args`, you set `var` as empty in a one-shot assignment and then run `command`.

Comment: Spot on! It seems I have some reading to do on variable assignment syntax. Thanks :)

Comment: It's more accurate to say the shell is *extremely* whitespace sensitive. It's not that `response= foo` is some sort of syntax error compared to `response=foo`; each is a completely valid syntax for two completely different operations. (The first calls the command `foo` with the variable `response` set to an empty string in its environment; the second is a variable assignment.)